# On Windows Machine how to check whether Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 or 2010 SPs are installed or not

Tags: batch-file

I just want to check that whether Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 or 2010 SPs are installed or not on my machine through a batch file.

If not installed I have exe to install.

Here I need to know how to check whether Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 or 2010 SPs are installed or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wanna use pwoershell ?

Comment: Its fine , but we should know whether Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 or 2010 SPs are installed or not .Thanks.

Comment: http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/yli628/archive/2008/01/16/powershell-script-to-list-installed-software-on-local-computer.aspx look at this.

Comment: Then you can just filter on Microsoft visual studio.